# Replace everything from beginning of line to equal sign

Tags: php, regex

For a content with the format:

```
KEY=VALUE
```

like:

```
LISTEN=I am listening.
```

I need to do some replacing using regex.  I want this regular expression to replace anything before the = with $key (making it have to be from beginning of line so a key like 'EN' wont replace a key like "TOKEN".

Here's what I'm using, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$content = preg_replace('~^'.$key.'\s?=[^\n$]+~iu',$newKey,$content);
```

Comment: What `doesn't seem to work` ? What are `$key`, `$newKey` and `$content` ?  Could you give some examples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$content = "foo=one\n"
         . "bar=two\n"
         . "baz=three\n";

$keys = array(
    'foo' => 'newFoo',
    'bar' => 'newBar',
    'baz' => 'newBaz',
);
foreach ( $keys as $oldKey => $newKey ) {
    $oldKey = preg_quote($oldKey, '#');
    $content = preg_replace("#^{$oldKey}( ?=)#m", "{$newKey}\\1", $content);
}

echo $content;
```

Output:

```
newFoo=one
newBar=two
newBaz=three
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'LISTEN=I am listening.';
$new_key = 'ÉCOUTER';

echo preg_replace('/^[^=]*=/', $new_key . '=', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question well, you need to switch the multi-line mode on using `m` modifier.

```
$content = preg_replace('/^'.preg_quote($key, '/').'(?=\s?=)/ium', $newKey, $content);
```

By the way I do recommend to escape the `$key` using `preg_quote` to avoid unexpected results.

So if the source content is this:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
HELLO=WORLD
KEY3=VALUE3
```

The result will be this (if `$key=HELLO` and `$newKey=BYE`):

```
KEY1=VALUE1
BYE=WORLD
KEY3=VALUE3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = 'LISTEN=I am listening.';
$key = 'LISTEN';
$newKey = 'NEW';


$content = preg_replace('~^'.$key.'(\s?=)~iu',$newKey.'$1',$content);

echo $content;
```

output is `NEW=I am listening.`

But is does not change on a partial match

```
$content = 'LISTEN=I am listening.';
$key = 'TEN';
$new_key = 'NEW';

$content = preg_replace('~^'.$key.'(\s?=)~iu',$newKey.'$1',$content);

echo $content;
```

Output is `LISTEN=I am listening.`

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.
\A is the start of a line, and the parentheses is for grouping things to keep/replace.

```
$new_content = preg_replace("/\A(.*)(=.*)/", "$key$2", $content);
```